# PHP Image cropping to square

Tags: php, image, resize, thumbnails, crop

I was using the following PHP script to create square thumbnails which I got here http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2009/08/cropping-an-image-to-make-square-thumbnails-in-php/

I was able to integrate this into my image upload script, which uploads full sized image and after that takes the uploaded image and creates a thumbnail from that.
The problem is the author of the script said, it will crop landscape and portrait images without problem. It crops landscape images perfectly, but as it faces portrait image, the output thumbnail will not be cropped, but it appears scaled down to fit the given square thumbnail height and the emtpy space on the sides will be filled with black color.
I know there is a way to fix this, but as I am relatively new to PHP I am not able to solve it.

Can someome with real experience in PHP fix this? 
Thank you in advance!

The script is here:
    $

```
 function square_crop($src_image, $dest_image, $thumb_size = 64, $jpg_quality = 90) {

// Get dimensions of existing image
$image = getimagesize($src_image);

// Check for valid dimensions
if( $image[0] <= 0 || $image[1] <= 0 ) return false;

// Determine format from MIME-Type
$image['format'] = strtolower(preg_replace('/^.*?\//', '', $image['mime']));

// Import image
switch( $image['format'] ) {
    case 'jpg':
    case 'jpeg':
        $image_data = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_image);
    break;
    case 'png':
        $image_data = imagecreatefrompng($src_image);
    break;
    case 'gif':
        $image_data = imagecreatefromgif($src_image);
    break;
    default:
        // Unsupported format
        return false;
    break;
}

// Verify import
if( $image_data == false ) return false;

// Calculate measurements
if( $image[0] & $image[1] ) {
    // For landscape images
    $x_offset = ($image[0] - $image[1]) / 2;
    $y_offset = 0;
    $square_size = $image[0] - ($x_offset * 2);
} else {
    // For portrait and square images
    $x_offset = 0;
    $y_offset = ($image[1] - $image[0]) / 2;
    $square_size = $image[1] - ($y_offset * 2);
}

// Resize and crop
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_size, $thumb_size);
if( imagecopyresampled(
    $canvas,
    $image_data,
    0,
    0,
    $x_offset,
    $y_offset,
    $thumb_size,
    $thumb_size,
    $square_size,
    $square_size
)) {

    // Create thumbnail
    switch( strtolower(preg_replace('/^.*\./', '', $dest_image)) ) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            return imagejpeg($canvas, $dest_image, $jpg_quality);
        break;
        case 'png':
            return imagepng($canvas, $dest_image);
        break;
        case 'gif':
            return imagegif($canvas, $dest_image);
        break;
        default:
            // Unsupported format
            return false;
        break;
    }

     } else {
    return false;
     }
    }
    ?>
```

And I call it like this - square_crop('source_image', 'destination_image', 65);

You can see the result here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/imgfl.png/

It happens only with portrait images, landscape images are cropped in a way that it fills the whole square.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post: It crops landscape images perfectly, but as it faces portrait image, the output thumbnail will not be cropped, but it appears scaled down to fit the given square thumbnail height and the emtpy space on the sides will be filled with black color.

Comment: You can see final result for portrait image cropping and resizing here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/imgfl.png/

Answer (score 1):

For cropping only, replace the imagecopyresampled() function with imagecopy().

The resampled performs an appropriate stretching or shrinking of the image if the source and destination coordinates and width and heights differ. imagecopy() doesn't.

Comment: But the script must maintain functionality to shrink cropped square image to thumbnail with size given in the call to the function.

Comment: I figured it out. In the portion where script detects if image is landscape or portrait, the if statement was written wrong it was **if( $image[0] & $image[1] ) {** which detects if the width and size are set, thus it never went pass the **else** statement which describes cropping when image is portrait.
All I had to do was change the if statement to **if( $image[0] > $image[1] ) {**. Thishow if width is larger than height it is landscape image and executes script after **if** statement, in the other case if width is less than height it is portrait and executes script after **else**.

Answer (score 0):

you should add an image ration inside the if() statement, so it will understand if it's portrait or landscape.

change the line below

```
// Calculate measurements
if( $image[0] > $image[1] ) {
```