# Create square 1:1 thumbnail in PHP

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

How can I set this code to return images in 1:1 (square)?

The purpose is to create a square (non stretched) thumbnail.

I've tried making changes in the 'if section'. I get a square image but stretched. I want it to be  cropped.

```
define('THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH', 150);
define('THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT', 150);

$source_image_path = {here the source filename};
$thumbnail_image_path = {here de thumb filename};

list($source_image_width, $source_image_height, $source_image_type) = getimagesize($source_image_path);
switch ($source_image_type) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
    $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_image_path);
    break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
    $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image_path);
    break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
    $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_image_path);
    break;
}
$source_aspect_ratio = $source_image_width / $source_image_height;
$thumbnail_aspect_ratio = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH / THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT;
if ($source_image_width <= THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH && $source_image_height <= THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT) {
    $thumbnail_image_width = $source_image_width;
    $thumbnail_image_height = $source_image_height;
} elseif ($thumbnail_aspect_ratio > $source_aspect_ratio) {
    $thumbnail_image_width = (int) (THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT * $source_aspect_ratio);
    $thumbnail_image_height = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT;
} else {
    $thumbnail_image_width = THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH;
    $thumbnail_image_height = (int) (THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH / $source_aspect_ratio);
}
$thumbnail_gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height);
imagecopyresampled($thumbnail_gd_image, $source_gd_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbnail_image_width, $thumbnail_image_height, $source_image_width, $source_image_height);
imagejpeg($thumbnail_gd_image, $thumbnail_image_path, 90);
```

*PS. It's not a duplicate, I've read several questions of this topic, but I'm unable to integrate it whit my code.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Image cropping to square](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107306/php-image-cropping-to-square)

Comment: Do you want the picture scaled and centred into a square or do you want a square cropped out of the middle of the photo

Comment: I want it to be cropped. (It's not a duplicate, I've read several questions of this topic, but I'm unable to integrate it whit my code).

Comment: you want to create thumb or you get error??

Comment: I want to create a thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255773/php-crop-image-to-fix-width-and-height-without-losing-dimension-ratio/3256004#3256004) did the trick

```
function crop_img($imgSrc){
    //getting the image dimensions
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgSrc);

    //saving the image into memory (for manipulation with GD Library)
    $myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc);

    // calculating the part of the image to use for thumbnail
    if ($width > $height) {
        $y = 0;
        $x = ($width - $height) / 2;
        $smallestSide = $height;
    } else {
        $x = 0;
        $y = ($height - $width) / 2;
        $smallestSide = $width;
    }

    // copying the part into thumbnail
    $thumbSize = min($width,$height);
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbSize, $thumbSize);
    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $myImage, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbSize, $thumbSize, $smallestSide, $smallestSide);

    unlink($imgSrc);
    imagejpeg($thumb,$imgSrc);
    @imagedestroy($myImage);
    @imagedestroy($thumb);
}
```

Found in: [PHP crop image to fix width and height without losing dimension ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255773/php-crop-image-to-fix-width-and-height-without-losing-dimension-ratio/3256004#3256004)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code this code uploads image to folder and renames the file and thumb will be created with same name

**HTML**

`<INPUT NAME="userfile[]" TYPE="file">`

image directory `"upimg/"`
thumb directory `thimg`

**php processing**

```
$rename = md5(rand() * time());
        $add = "upimg/" . $rename . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $add)) {
            echo "Successfully uploaded the image";
            chmod("$add", 0777);
        } else {
            exit;
        }
        $n_width = 200;
        $n_height = 200;
        $tsrc = "thimg/" . $rename . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        if (!($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "image/jpeg" OR $_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "image/gif")) {
            exit;
        }
        if ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "image/gif") {
            $im = ImageCreateFromGIF($add);
            $width = ImageSx($im);
            $height = ImageSy($im);
            $newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($n_width, $n_height);
            imageCopyResized($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $n_width, $n_height, $width, $height);
            if (function_exists("imagegif")) {
                Header("Content-type: image/gif");
                ImageGIF($newimage, $tsrc);
            } elseif (function_exists("imagejpeg")) {
                Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
                ImageJPEG($newimage, $tsrc);
            }
            chmod("$tsrc", 0777);
        }
        if ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == "image/jpeg") {
            $im = ImageCreateFromJPEG($add);
            $width = ImageSx($im);
            $height = ImageSy($im);
            $newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($n_width, $n_height);
            imageCopyResized($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $n_width, $n_height, $width, $height);
            ImageJpeg($newimage, $tsrc);
            chmod("$tsrc", 0777);
        }
```

Comment: From reading the code I'm guessing this returns a 200x200px thumbnail with the original image resized and centered in the middle (black background). What I need is the original image cropped and scaled to a square.